# How to assign Textbox value to the other textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two textboxes in my view,

My requirement is when I enter some text in the first textbox automatically that value should be assigned to second text box when I leave first textbox. using jquery or javascript.

thanks for your help

EDIT:

For Some reason this code is not inserting the value into seconed textbox.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/9tEV2/4/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Capture the onchange event of the first textbox and in the event handler assign the first textbox value to second one.

Something like:

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="text" id="anotherName"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#name").change(function(){
   $("#anotherName").val($(this).val());
  });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Cybernate.. for reason its not working for me..http://jsfiddle.net/9tEV2/4/

Comment: The reason was jQuery was not reference in the jsFiddle post. Updated it. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/9tEV2/5/

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#textbox1').blur(function(e) {

    $('#textbox2').val($(this).val());

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Non-jQuery solution:

```
A.onblur = function() { 
    B.value = this.value;
};
```

Where `A` and `B` are references to the text-box elements.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/9tEV2/

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Hi</strike>

<strike>try with</strike>

```
$('#Text1').keypress(function () {
    $('#Text2').val($(this).val());
});
```

<strike>I hope it's helpful</strike>

Do not consider this post, I didn't read correctly the question

Comment: This will change the value on each keypress, even on the non-alphanumeric ones. The author also asked for when the focus is lost. This could be also be expensive, depending on the amount of keystrokes.

Comment: @Eli: Sorry! I've not saw "when I leave first text box",I'll edit the post now!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txt1").change(function () {

           $("#text2").val($(this).val());// For Single textBox
            $("#filltext").find("input:text").val($(this).val()) // Fill textbox1 value to multiple textboxes present in a single div(filltext is Division ID)
        });
    })
</script>`
```